# Possible issue with db->loadObjectList() with Joomla 3.0

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

We have developed a shoutbox which works fine of Joomla 1.5 and 2.5. I make it Joomla 3.0 compatible by changing the version in the XML and a few other bits n bobs.

When I try and load the page that the shoutbox module is assigned to, I get the following error messages:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\XXX\libraries\legacy\module\helper.php on line 150

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$content in C:\wamp\www\XXX\templates\system\html\modules.php on line 17
```

I narrowed it down to a single line that is causing the problem, which is:

```
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

This line comes from the following function to retrieve the shouts:

```
function getShouts($number, $timezone, $message) {
    global $mainframe;
    $shouts = array();
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM #__shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC';
    $db->setQuery($query , 0 , $number);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $i=0;
    $timezone=$timezone*60*60;
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
        $shouts[$i]->id = $row->id;
        $shouts[$i]->name = $row->name;
        $adjustedtime = strtotime($row->when) + $timezone;
        $shouts[$i]->when = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $adjustedtime);
        $shouts[$i]->ip = $row->ip;
        $shouts[$i]->msg = $row->msg;
        $i++;
    }
    return $shouts;
}
```

I honestly have no idea why I'm getting these 2 errors as they module works perfectly in previous Joomla versions. I've tried using different methods to get the shouts but nothing worked.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening and have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it worked for you in 2.5 but you need 
http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/9-developer/135-database-upgrades-in-joomla-16.html
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

and also you shouldn't use the & here
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
since objects are always passed by reference.

Comment: I tried using the Joomla 1.6 method to set a query from the link you gave me and removed the `&`, however the error still occurs. I am pretty sure it's to do with `$db->loadObjectList();`

Comment: What happens if you var_dump it?
Remember that it no longer extends JObject so be sure not to use any methods from there.

Comment: it turns out the database table wasn't being created upon installation of the module. I created it manually and added a row and the shoutbox worked, so just need to get the table created and everything should be fine. thanks